# import timboudreau netty-http-client into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netty

I start working on the open source project netty-http-client(https://github.com/timboudreau/netty-http-client)

and I have cloned netty-http-client and mastfrog-parent, however, when I import those to eclipse, eclipse told me the pom.xml of netty-http-client was wrong for "**Non-resolveable parent POM**", I have no idea about this, anyone help!

Comment: you should include pom file in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the repositories in which Tim has the mastfrog parent pom artifact.

From the readme:

> To use with Maven, add the Maven repo to your project as described here. Then add groupId com.mastfrog artifactId netty-http-client to your POM file.

Just add

```
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>timboudreau-builds</id>
    <name>timboudreau.com builds</name>
    <url>http://timboudreau.com/builds/plugin/repository/everything/</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

to your project's pom.xml
(I'd actually change that "updatePolicy=never" to something more sensible, however).

Comment: I hope he publishes to central maven repo someday :)

Answer (score 0):

I  have worked it out.
It should install(mvn install) the parent pom in this url https://github.com/timboudreau/mastfrog-parent